# How to install Oracle Client 32 bit on RHEL 64 bit OS

Tags: oracle12c, rhel7, cognos-10, oracleclient

Would like to install Oracle Client (11g or 12c or 18c) 32 bit version on RHEL 7 64 bit version OS. Came to know that Oracle software 32 bit wont work on 64 bit RHEL verion. This is required for cognos usage. How this can be tackled.

Comment: **Usually** it is vice versa - 64-bit software won't work on 32-bit computers (it can't). Your situation is different; you're saying that 32-bit Client won't work on 64-bit computer. "Came to know" is what exactly? Someone told you / you read it in documentation / something else?

Comment: Yes. Read few links that Oracle database Software 32 bit wont work on Linux 64 bit. But few link have mentioned that Oracle Client 32 bit will work on 64 bit OS through different way installation. Need to know how it can be done. Would be great If get some help. Our main requirement is cognos installation on RHEL 7 64 bit (will be done by Cognos team) where it will work only with Oracle client 32 bit run time or administrator software.

Comment: Can I get a suggestion

Comment: Unfortunately, not from me. I don't use Linux so I can't say anything based on my own experience. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist. Good luck!